# ASP.NET get related object through bind

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, webforms

I have the following class in C#:

```
public class Client
{
    public string name{get;set;}
    public User user{get;set;}
}
```

and the class:

```
public class User
{
    public string email{get;set;}
}
```

I access all the objects of Client through a data source, and I am displaying the info through a data list. How do I display `Client.user.email`?

Thanks

EDIT:

To clarify, these classes are just an example. All the fields are actually public with set and get.

The question is, I have `<%# Eval("user") %>` how do I access `<%# Eval("user.email") %>`

Edit:

I am loading my data with Entity Framework. All the objects are being received with a web service

Comment: make all of the `public` and you can also change them to properties instead of fields.

Comment: It is public, I gave this as an example. My classes are much more complicated than this

Comment: You need to provide an example of how you're loading the fields/properties of your object from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Eval` is normally return the object from class `User`, so the final code will be:

```
<%# (User)(Eval("user")).email %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Habib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/961113/habib) has stated in your question comments you should add public properties to retrieve the values.

```
public class Client
{
    public string name{get;set;}
    public User user{get;set;}
}

public class User
{
    public string email{get;set;}
}
```